# Open Graph action not approved, I see Facebook test users used it and it worked, feedback message is wrong

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, tagging

I have submitted an Open Graph action that tags users. It was not approved before because they couldn't perform the actions. I made the (still test) interface more usable so actions could be performed easily.

When logging in with **Facebook test users** I can see that they **performed the actions perfectly** (they tagged users, actions appear in their feeds, etc), but again it has not been approved.

More strange, the contradictory message that I get is:

> *Status: Changes needed*
>
> **Congratulations, your Open Graph action submission has been approved. Thanks for your contribution to the Facebook Platform**.
>
> Please make changes below and resubmit for review.

What should I do now?